# Issue in Updating App to appstore with Associated Domains enabled

Tags: app-store-connect, deep-linking, associated-domains

While uploading app to Itunes Store I am getting following error, can any one please help me solving this?

My app supports Deeplinking and Universal Linkings via Website and Emails so I have added associated domains in my Capabilities file.

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'applinks:www.some-app.com/*'
>   for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in
>   'Payload/myapp.app/myapp' is not supported."

I can not disable this option as this is required for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to StackOverFlow. It looks like the syntax for the entry is incorrect.

`'applinks:www.some-app.com/*` is not a correct entry as you can only define domains and not paths in the associated domains entry. Please correct it to `'applinks:www.some-app.com'` and give it a try.

As per Apple's docs, you must specify the paths etc. in the site association file: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

There you can specify the regex/path pattern.